# Pandas - Columns not read though Present

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have following set of data.

```
url, team1, team2, win_toss, bat_or_bowl, outcome, win_game, date,day_n_night, ground, rain, duckworth_lewis, match_id, type_of_match
"espncricinfo-t20/145227.html","Western Australia","Victoria","Victoria","bat","Western Australia won by 8 wickets (with 47 balls remaining)","Western Australia"," Jan 12 2005","1"," Western Australia Cricket Association Ground,Perth","0","0","145227","T20"
"espncricinfo-t20/212961.html","Australian Institute of Sports","New Zealand Academy","New Zealand Academy","bowl","Match tied",""," Jul 7 2005 ","0"," Albury Oval, Brisbane","0","0","212961","T20"
"espncricinfo-t20/216598.html","Air India","New South Wales","Air India","bowl","Air India won by 7 wickets (with 5 balls remaining)","Air India"," Aug 19 2005 ","0"," M Chinnaswamy Stadium, Bangalore","0","0","216598","T20"
"espncricinfo-t20/216620.html","Karnataka State Cricket Association XI","Bradman XI","Bradman XI","bowl","Karnataka State Cricket Association XI won by 33 runs","Karnataka State Cricket Association XI"," Aug 20 2005 ","0"," M Chinnaswamy Stadium, Bangalore","0","0","216620","T20"
"espncricinfo-t20/216633.html","Chemplast","Bradman XI","Chemplast","bat","Bradman XI won by 6 wickets (with 13 balls remaining)","Bradman XI"," Aug 20 2005 ","0"," M Chinnaswamy Stadium, Bangalore","0","0","216633","T20"
```

**This is from python console :**

**

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv("sample.txt" , quotechar = '\"')
>>> df.shape
(9, 14)


>>> df.columns
Index([u'url', u' team1', u' team2', u' win_toss', u' bat_or_bowl',
       u' outcome', u' win_game', u' date', u' day_n_night', u' ground',
       u' rain', u' duckworth_lewis', u' match_id', u' type_of_match'],
      dtype='object')


>>> df.url.head()
0    espncricinfo-t20/145227.html
1    espncricinfo-t20/212961.html
2    espncricinfo-t20/216598.html
3    espncricinfo-t20/216620.html
4    espncricinfo-t20/216633.html
Name: url, dtype: object


>>> df.team1.head()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2744, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'team1'



>>> df.iloc[1:2]
                            url                           team1  \
1  espncricinfo-t20/212961.html  Australian Institute of Sports

                 team2             win_toss  bat_or_bowl     outcome  \
1  New Zealand Academy  New Zealand Academy         bowl  Match tied

   win_game          date   day_n_night                  ground   rain  \
1       NaN   Jul 7 2005              0   Albury Oval, Brisbane      0

    duckworth_lewis   match_id  type_of_match
1                 0     212961            T20
```

We can see the column team1 exists but i am unable to retrieve it from Df. I get this error for all columns except for first . Could anyone please help me find the problem here ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a leading space:

```
u' team1'
```

in the column so it raises `KeyError`

do this:

```
pd.read_csv("sample.txt" , quotechar = '\"', skipinitialspace=True)
```

so the csv is read and ignores the leading space

See the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)

Comment: Thanks EdChum. This looks more a elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

There are whitespaces in column names, need remove them by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
```

Comment: I will try this. Thank you. But why does df.shape show exact column count  ?

Comment: columns is array of items, so length is OK. Only problem is in items - some contains whitespaces - `u' team1', u' team2'` but need `u'team1', u'team2',`

Comment: Thank you , +1 for a new way of handling it. I will go with EdChum answer as it looks more elegant. Appreciate your response !

Comment: Glad can help you.